# How can I show a specific page to a person that has logged in

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase-authentication

I am using a nodejs server to render ejs files as requested. I want only an authenticated user to make the request for his/her profile. If an un-registered user makes that request I want to redirect the user to the login page.

Following is the logic implemented on the node server

```
router.get('/profile',function(req,res){
    const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ','')
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
    .then(function(decodedToken) {
    let uid = decodedToken.uid;
    console.log(uid)
    res.redirect('profile.ejs');
    }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
    console.log("error")
    res.status(401).send({"error":"Please Authenticate first"})
    });
})
```

The following is how the client requests for the page

```
$('#user-info').click(function () {
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
        // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
        console.log(idToken)
        fetch('/profile',{
            method: "get",
            headers: {
                'Content-type':'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${idToken}`
            }
        }).then((data)=>{
            console.log(data)
        })
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle error
        checkIfLoggedIn()
    });
})
```

Comment: First of all, you should not set the Content-Type of a GET request. Would you care to explain the actuall problem? The code that you have shared is basically the snippets from firbase dev docs.

Comment: I want that to render the profile.ejs page only if the user is registered, else I want to render the homepage

Answer (score 0):

The existing catch handles errors occurred calling `getIdToken`. Please add a specific `.catch()` to handle the error case for the `fetch` accordingly, e.g.:

```
    fetch('/profile',{
        method: "get",
        headers: {
            'Content-type':'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${idToken}`
        }
    }).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    }
```